# More Efficient Way To Copy Data To Many Servers

Tags: c#, xml, copy

Here are the basics of the scenario.  I have a small block of data (10MB) that needs to get copied (within my C# app) from one source server to approximately 10,000 different destination folders residing on probably 25 different servers (400 dest folders per server).  I have all the access rights, etc, and my only hangup is in deciding what **method** would be the fastest and most efficient.  Time to completion is the bigger priority within any answer.  Unfortunately, I cannot accept other "solutions" as it is what it is.  Sorry.

Some of my options are:

1. Copy the data from source to 10,000 destinations with asyncronous copy commands.
2. Copy the data from source to each of the 25 servers, then copy asyncronously from each location on the server to their final 10,000 destination folders on their respective server.
3. Other options??

From a logic standpoint option 2 seems to make the most sense but I'm curious for input.  I'm not clear on how non-local copy commands are processed by the OS.  Is the program coming through the network back through my source server then onto the destination?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a specific programming question.

Comment: Are you expecting us to say something like, "use #2 rather than #1" (+ justification) or are you expecting us to give you teh codez for "the best" solution?

Comment: I don't need code.  Trying to figure if either one makes better use of I/O or if they are both equally limited. Or maybe there's something better, but the servers can only function as drop points.

Comment: Since I can only use the server folders as drop points and cannot have the servers do any work for me, I'm simply going to be limited by I/O with either option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward solution is, yes, copy once to a root location on each of the 25 servers using File.Copy().  Then, tell each server to copy the data from that root location to the target 400 locations by pushing them commands.  The exact format of the command depends on what type of servers they are.

If they are unix servers, send the command via SSH or SCP.

If they are FTP servers, some servers provide a remote-to-remote copy command that is more efficient than re-uploading the same data.

If they are Windows servers, you can use a .CMD file, or PowerShell or something else (see here for more ideas: https://serverfault.com/questions/116166/windows-how-to-start-a-file-copy-job-on-a-remote-server-without-passing-through)

However, if you actually control the 25 servers yourself, just write a command line program that monitors a "drop folder".  Anytime it receives the 10MB file in the drop folder, automatically propagate the file to the 400 target locations.

Comment: I don't control the servers at all and only have access to the folders I need.  Your shared solution is wonderful that I'll keep handy for other stuff for sure.

Comment: Voted up 1 because I might have a chance at getting PSRemoting enabled.

Comment: Yep, I'm good.  Thanks.  I didn't see this in my initial Google "research" cause I was just plain asking the wrong question.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear things are looking up!

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common operational requirement.

I have solved it in the past very successfully using [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29) (it's much more robust than xcopy).

If you copy from one source to 10,000 separate servers, you will saturate the NIC on the one source.  You are better off having a dropoff folder on each server, and having each server look for changes in the dropoff folder and copy them to the various target folders on that server.

Comment: Sounds good and exactly my thinking, but unfortunately I can't have the servers look for anything and execute anything.  All functionality has to come from the source.  Servers function solely as drop points and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

The network (unless you have a slow hard drive on the initial distributor or are running gigabit or higher Ethernet between the servers) will be your biggest problem. To split up the bandwidth you might want to implement a pyramid-like scheme.

For example, take a list of all the servers you need to copy the data to, remove the N servers with the fastest connection and split it up the remaining list into N lists of equal size. Send the payload along with the lists to the removed servers. The servers will then accept the data, as well as the list of servers they are responsible for transferring data to. The servers would then take the list and repeat the procedure until all servers have a copy of the data.

Obviously, this all depends on your network topology, and you should try with different values of N to see which are fastest, but this is how optimized P2P distribution works: Send the data to the fastest peers first and let them resend out to others.

Comment: Unfortunately, my servers are operating simply as drop points and will not be transferring anything themselves.  Am I equally limited with both options I described?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you implement the dropoff folder idea mentioned by Eric J, (which is generally a good idea), you'll still be bound by disk I/O, so fast is going to be relative to the destination's physical medium.

Here is a key question for you: Are you going to be modifying this data once its in your 10,000 directories? If the answer is no, strongly consider symlinking your 10,000 destinations to each server's dropoff directory.

Comment: Yeah, data will get changed.  Symlinking is unfortunately something that wouldn't work for this specific project.